# Darboux theorem and symplectic 2-sphere

Tags: smooth-manifolds, curvature, symplectic-geometry

Very rougly said, the Darboux Theorem states that all symplectic manifolds (of the same finite dimension) "look the same", i.e. their symplectic form could be brought to look like the standard one - $dx_i \land dx_j$...one of the effects is that the symplectic structure doesn't "encode" curvature.

But on the symplectic 2-sphere, the symplectic form is $\omega =r^2sin\theta d\theta \land d\phi$, which is different...

What I am missing?

Comment: $\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta=-\mathrm{d}z$

Comment: So are you saying that the two structures are equivalent via a symplectomorphism? And why it isn't possible to made an analogous transformation in a riemannian manifold?

Comment: You could have use cylindrical polars instead of the spherical polars, and this gives $\omega=\mathrm{d}\theta\wedge\mathrm{d}z$ which was a result known to Archimedes (though not in this language).

Comment: Ah, now I get...thank you!!

Comment: Darboux's theorem states that LOCALLY all symplectic manifolds look the same.